# Monic polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In my lecture notes, the following is stated:

> $(x^m-a^m)/(x-a)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $m-1$ with integer
>   coefficients if $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Why is this true? How can I prove it?

Comment: You also need $a$ to be an integer. Have you ever seen a geometric sum? Or a geometric series even?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do long division, to write

$$
(x^m - a^m) = (x - a) q(x) + b
$$
where $b$ is a polynomial of degree less than that of $x-a$, i.e., a constant.

Now plug in $x = a$ on both sides to conclude that $b = 0$. So you've got 
$$
(x^m - a^m) = (x - a) q(x)
$$
where 
$$
q(x) = c_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \ldots + c_0
$$

(You know it has degree $m-1$ because degrees add when you multiply polynomials).

2. In this product, the only term with degree $m$ is $x * c_{m-1}x^{m-1}$; on the left, the only such term in $x^m$. Hence $c_{m-1} = 1$.

This doesn't address is "has integer coefficients" because that's not true without the further assumption that $a$ is an integer. (Consider $x^2 - \frac{1}{4}$, for instance). But @martini's answer handles that if you're willing to make the extra assumption.

Answer (score 0):

By polynomial long division or (if you know the result) by direct multiplication, we have, that
$$ x^m - a^m = (x-a) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} x^ia^{m-1-i} $$
which is integer iff $a$ is.